# How do I find my own questions?

Tags: support

I cannot find a link to my own questions (that I asked). Nor can I find anything obvious in searching for "my questions" or "How can I find my own questions".

EDIT: OK, So I have a partial answer.

If I click on the bar on the top of the window, where the reputation and badge count is, I get a list of my questions. Except that it does not show a question that I asked earlier today -- it only shows one from months ago.

Is this a simple "a cache that updates infrequently" issue -- if so, I should see my other question tomorrow, right?

Otherwise, what happened to (and how do I find) my "missing" question?

Answer (score 3):

I see two questions on your [AskDifferent profile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/198208/keybounce), one from last year and one asked a few minutes *after* you asked the question on meta. It might help to add a screenshot next time the problem happens to you, otherwise it's difficult to see what could be wrong.